# Eclipse AWS Plugin can not install SDK

Tags: eclipse, plugins, amazon-web-services, eclipse-plugin, cloud

I have installed Eclipse for JEE Kepler 4.3 When I install the AWS plugin it works fine, but then fails to install the sdk.

Error logs:

```
 java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
 at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1025)
 at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:999)
 at com.amazonaws.eclipse.sdk.ui.AbstractSdkManager.downloadSDK(AbstractSdkManager.java:345)
 at com.amazonaws.eclipse.sdk.ui.AbstractSdkManager.access$3(AbstractSdkManager.java:300)
 at com.amazonaws.eclipse.sdk.ui.AbstractSdkManager$SdkDownloadJob.run(AbstractSdkManager.java:259)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Full discription of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYwN3.jpg

Has anyone else had similar problems or know of a possible solution?

Note: Have tried to install on multiple PC's using Kelper and Juno.

Comment: Maybe the file gets corrupted by some network services or is not accessed correctly (e.g. wrong proxy settings). Did you try to check it outside company network (if relevant)?